# TextField IME padding in LazyColumn , Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Problem : TextField (inside lazy column) text goes below the keybaord**

**Explanation :**

I have a LazyColumn that contains a list of items displaying text fields , In the manifest the activity has *`windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`* and I am also setting the flag        *`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window,false)`* in the onCreate Method before setContent and I want to make text appear above the keyboard at all times for smoother editing experience !

Using Accompanist Library providing Window Insets to give padding to the Box like this

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).navigationBarsWithImePadding()){
    LazyColumn() {
         items(myItems) { item->
              ItemComposable(item)
         }
    }
}
```

As you can see , there's navigationBarsWithImePadding on the box , but it does't work since the text goes below the keyboard , I tried setting the modifier on LazyColumn but then it provides padding with the LazyColumn relative to other items outside of the box !

so I tried *`contentPadding`*

```
LazyColumn(contentPadding=insets.ime.toPaddingValues(additionalBottom=insets.navigationBars.bottom.dp)) {
    items(editor.blocks) { block ->
        RenderBlock(block)
    }
}
```

Again did't work , since the content padding is applied to the last item / or after it , The keyboard goes above the text

Replacing LazyColumn with a simple Column and using a **verticalScroll** modifier causes the same problem , Because the list can be long vertical scroll becomes a need

Comment: All the solutions given here will probably work under some conditions !
To track the issue go to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120
It still hasn't been fixed

Comment: Also this issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237190748 and this issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266094055

Answer (score 3):

If you use Column, you can refer to the following code snippet:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        // other modifiers
        .verticalScroll(scrollState, reverseScrolling = true)
        .navigationBarsWithImePadding(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
)
```

Comment: adding "reverseScrolling = true" helped. Also, "navigationBarsWithImePadding()" doesn't work now. I used "imePadding()" instead.

Comment: @TimJohn Well, the version should be upgraded, you can refer to the `accompanist/insets`  library: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/
use:
Modifier.navigationBarsPadding().imePadding()

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't using the accompanist/insets library, just the regular compose libraries. Just noticed that the OP was talking about this library.

Comment: Yes, now compose’s built-in modifiers have been built in, and accompanist is just a transitional solution for everyone in the past

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have a [solution](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120#comment36) for it. Just follow these steps below:

Step 1: In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
 </activity>
```

Step 2: In your Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    setContent {

        AppTheme {

           ProvideWindowInsets(
               windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true,
               consumeWindowInsets = false,
           ) {
              // your content
             }
         }
     }
```

Step 3:

```
LazyColumn(
  modifier = Modifier
    .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
    .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())
    .height(LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp)
    .fillMaxWidth(),
 ) {
      // your TextField items
   }
```

Step 4:

```
 // init your CoroutineScope
 val  coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

 // init your BringIntoViewRequester
 val  bringIntoViewRequester = BringIntoViewRequester()

 // use them in your TextField modifier
 modifier = Modifier
   /* ... your other modifiers*/
    .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
    .onFocusEvent {
        if (it.isFocused || it.hasFocus) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(250)
                bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ideally please summarize the solution here. That there is an issue is an info beyond the link, so this is not 100% link only. But it is quite close.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch, I summarized the solution above

Comment: I recommend to keep the link. Because a) the issue link is still valuable info b) it protects you, serving as as much contribution as needed.

Comment: For me it doesn't work. If the keyboard covers the field before bringIntoView() is called, the field goes outside the composition and loses the focus. The delay of 250 ms can work on some cases, but some recent samsung devices (tested on Galaxy s20 FE) have basically no animation on keyboard.

Comment: I proposed a solution another solution [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120#comment40). On my case I manually scroll thee LazyColumn of the exact amount of scroll needed to keep the field visible. I also add an item at the bottom of the LazyColumn which has the height = totalKeyboardHeight - currentKeyboardHeight, to keep the lazycolumn always scrollable. When a field is focused, I scroll the lazycolumn of the exact amount needed AND instantly because the animation of the keyboard must be slower than the scroll of the LazyColumn.

Comment: Where to add these code windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true,
               consumeWindowInsets = false,

Comment: ProvideWindowInsets doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry but whenever a solution is this complicated, it's not a solution.