# Column does not scroll to TextField on focus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a long input page with multiple `TextField`s inside it. But when a `TextField` gains focus, the keyboard appears and the `Column` (which is `scrollable`) does not scroll to the specific `TextField`, and sometimes the keyboard overlaps the field.

I tried to see if this is an Android issue, and no, in normal Android View, the focused `TextInputLayout` will make the `ScrollView` scroll so that it's showing.

I tried using `RelocationRequester` in Compose when the `TextField` gains focus, but it doesn't seem to do anything, and it only has one method.

Is there a fix to this? Or do I need to wait until Focus and Relocation APIs are stable in Compose?

Comment: this is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120) and duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138999/textfield-ime-padding-in-lazycolumn-compose), not yet answered

Comment: Please, check if this sample helps you: https://github.com/nglauber/JetpackComposePlayground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/nglauber/jetpackcomposeplayground/screens/FocusRequesterScreen.kt