# visibility of a part of screen when keyboard is open in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have code like this and I want the button on the bottom to be visible when keyboard is opened to edit the textfield.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .imePadding(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(text = "LARGE TITLE", fontSize = 32.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp))
                OutlinedTextField(value = "Sample Text", onValueChange = {})
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text(text = "Sample Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have put  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest. I achieved my purpose by adding reverseScrolling = true (.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState(), reverseScrolling = true)) to the column modifier with help of an answer of @Halifax to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138999/textfield-ime-padding-in-lazycolumn-compose). I'm wondering how this has solved the issue exactly. Can I use this approach in similar views? I'm worried that it might cause some weird behavior if the screen got more complicated.
[image: without reverseScrolling = true]

[image: with reverseScrolling = true]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different solution that keeps the button in the column. It uses the `BringIntoViewRequester` to scroll the button into view whenever the size of the column is changed.

```
    setContent {
        val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val bringButtonIntoView: () -> Unit = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(1)
                bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
            }
        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier.imePadding()) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .onSizeChanged { bringButtonIntoView() },
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(text = "LARGE TITLE", fontSize = 32.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp))
                OutlinedTextField(value = "Sample Text", onValueChange = {})
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Button(
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester),
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Sample Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had  implemented a similar code but I had put bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView() in textField's onClick. But my problem there was that bringIntoView() was called before the keyboard was opened and I had to add delay. By the way my question is mostly about exact effect of reverse scrolling here and it has solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to ensure that the activity's `windowSoftInputMode` is set to `adjustResize`

```
<activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Secondly `setContent` code will be like

```
setContent {
    Scaffold(
        contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets.safeDrawing,
        bottomBar = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text(text = "Sample Button")
                }
            }
        }
    ) { padding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .consumedWindowInsets(padding)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "LARGE TITLE", fontSize = 32.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp))
            OutlinedTextField(value = "Sample Text", onValueChange = {})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already done the first part in manifest. Your solution seems good except that the column might be longer in a more complicated view and we may not want the button to be always visible at the bottom. By the way my question is mostly about exact effect of reverse scrolling here and it has solved my issue.